# Overwriting geodatabase that has joined features in ArcGIS Pro for ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

The project is for an outreach program that does outreach either onsite (point), onsite/outreach by 1 - 3 mile radius (point with buffer), zip outreach by zipcode (polygon), and block navigation (polygon).

These are all of the steps I took:

1. Geocode the onsite layer and the onsite/ outreach by 1-3 mile radius layer. These layers had specific addresses so I was able to geocode them.
2. Created/ Traced polygon features for the zip outreach layer. There are about 15 polygon features that are separate agencies, but I have them as one feature class.
3. Created/ Traced polygon features for the block navigation layer. This is similar to the zip outreach layer because it consists of about 15 separate polygons that are under one feature class.
4. The two polygon layers (zip outreach and block navigation) are drawn in feature classes so there is no data attached to them. I joined a CSV to each of them by a UniqueID. 
   (The last 4 steps were done in ArcGIS Pro)
5. The finished map needs to be uploaded onto ArcGIS Online and converted into a web mapping application for the end users.
6. When I add my zipped geodatabase into 'My Content' the joined files don't transfer. Neither polygon layer has any of the data joined from the CSV.

Work Around (that didn't work):

1. So I just decided to join the layers through ArcGIS Online's analysis tools. They are limited on tools, but they have the basics so I decided to join my tables to my layers through web map.
2. That worked fine for the time, especially because I had to get a finished product for some presentations.
3. A week later I received a new dataset from a colleague.
4. The new dataset had more point features to add (onsite, onsite/ outreach by 1-3 miles) 
   It also had new polygon features to add (zip outreach only)
5. So I went to 'My Content' on ArcGIS Online and went to my geodatabase (hosted feature layer) so I could overwrite it with my new set of data.
6. All the schema was structured the same and the geodatabase updated properly, except for my polygon layer.
7. Since I joined the layer through online the layer is only pointing back to its feature layer that was created from the analysis. In the web map when I click on 'Item Details' on the layer, it brings me back to the feature layer. The layer should be pointing towards the geodatabase.

The main problem is when I overwrite my geodatabase; the updated information is added to each layer successfully, but the new feature classes I add don't transfer to the web map or web application. So every time I overwrite the geodatabase, I have to create a new web map and web mapping application. This is very time consuming because I have to redo the symbology and queries every time I overwrite my geodatabase. I know schema changes can affect a geodatabase and its updates, but the schema of the table has remained the same.

Is there an easier solution to keeping my geodatabase updated?

Comment: In the original step 4, did you export the features into a new feature class after you set up the join?

Comment: So you're saying I should try exporting/ saving the joined feature class as a new feature class? Then uploading that back into my geodatabase?

Comment: That should fix the problem in the first step 6 you have listed here.  When you join features your are only creating a relationship between the datasets.  In order for that to exist in a feature class you need to export into a new feature class.  The original only retains the joined data within the ArcMAP interface.

Comment: Yes, I had already done that, but I am confused on how to keep the geodatabase updated with the join. If I draw new polygons and rejoin them to the new dataset, will my geodatabase overwrite successfully. I don't want to have to redo the web map/ application each time by updating the symbology and queries.

Comment: Looks like this may be the tool to use: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/synchronize-changes.htm

Comment: I tried going through the distributed geodatabase process, but I keep this error while I am trying to Add Global ID's = ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution. I tried to Add Global ID's to the point locations exclusively (I thought the join would be the cause of the error), but I still received the same error. If you have created a distributed geodatabase before, some more help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this tool mainly for enterprise geodatabases? @SteveC

Comment: I don't see anything stating that.  Perhaps someone else with more enterprise experience could comment here.